# Andorid AlertDialog multiselect - allow user to add choice

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, multi-select

I'm trying to create an alert dialog where the user can select multiple options from a pre-defined list, but if the option(s) they want to select aren't there, they can add them (via an edittext and "add" button).

So far, I've added the edittext and button to the top of the dialog using setCustomTitle, and I'm able to add the item to my source data list, but I can't figure out how to reapply this to the list in the dialog.

(Filter model just has a string and a boolean to determine whether it's selected, so if the user reopens the dialog I can set the selected items)

Here's my code so far...

```
 private void selectSomething() {
        AlertDialog.Builder selectSomethingBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.common_multichoice_dialog_header, null);
        Button addButton = header.findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        EditText et = header.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        selectSomethingBuilder.setCustomTitle(header);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            cuisineList.add(new filterModel(et.getText().toString(), true));
            boolean[] selectedItems2 = new boolean[cuisineList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < cuisineList.size(); i++) {
                selectedItems2[i] = cuisineList.get(i).isSelected();
            }
            String[] updatedList = cuisineList.stream().map(filterModel::toString).toArray(String[]::new);

            //What to do here? How do I update the list of items with the newly added item

            et.setText("");

        });

        boolean[] selectedItems = new boolean[cuisineList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cuisineList.size(); i++) {
            selectedItems[i] = cuisineList.get(i).isSelected();
        }
        selectSomethingBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(cuisineList.stream().map(filterModel::toString).toArray(String[]::new), selectedItems,
                (dialog, which, isChecked) -> cuisineList.get(which).setSelected(isChecked));
        selectSomethingBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id1) -> {
            setCuisineChips();
        });
        AlertDialog selectItems = selectSomethingBuilder.create();

        selectItems.show();
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-alertdialog-multichoice.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got there by extending AlertDialog.Builder - for anyone who comes across this, here's the class I'm using:

```
public class multichoiceUserAddableDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {
    private final Context context;
    private final MultiAdapter adapter;

    public multichoiceUserAddableDialog(Context context, List<filterModel> selectList) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_multichoice_dialog_header, null);
        Button addButton = header.findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        EditText et = header.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        this.setCustomTitle(header);
        adapter = new MultiAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, selectList);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            selectList.add(new filterModel(et.getText().toString(), et.getText().toString(), true));
            et.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
        setAdapter(adapter, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
          
        });

    }

    @Override
    public AlertDialog create() {
        AlertDialog x = super.create();
        x.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ((filterModel) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).setSelected(!((filterModel) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).isSelected());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return x;
    }

    private class MultiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<filterModel> {
        private List<filterModel> selectList;
        ViewHolder holder;

        public MultiAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<filterModel> selectList) {
            super(context, resource, selectList);
            this.selectList = selectList;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            CheckedTextView itemTV;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.itemTV = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.itemTV.setText(selectList.get(position).getText());
            holder.itemTV.setChecked(selectList.get(position).isSelected());
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

This is then used like this:

```
 multichoiceUserAddableDialog selectSomethingBuilder = new multichoiceUserAddableDialog(mContext, activityList);
        selectSomethingBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id1) -> {
            setActivityChips();
        });
        AlertDialog selectItems = selectSomethingBuilder.create();
     
        selectItems.show();
```

filterModel has a text field and a boolean (and any other fields you want), and the header layout has an editText and a button (plus a textview with some static text).